# Android achartengine, changine point color of line graph dynamically

Tags: android, char, achartengine

Is there any way to change the color of achartengine line graph's line point programmatically based on the y-axis values (i.e, if the value is above 199 then orange or if it is less than 100 then red).
Here is my code,

```
XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer2.setLineWidth(1.5f);
            renderer2.setColor(Color.RED);
            renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
            renderer2.setFillPoints(true);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
```

but in the above i can not give different color for line point it takes the line color.
also I have attached my resulted graph in which I need to changes

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to write code for it in achart engine source code.

Comment: @dd619 but I could not find source code from code.google.com

Comment: download from here http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another series that would only contain the points that must be orange and add the series after the other line series.

Comment: but what should do if number of points is not constant means?

Comment: I don't understand the question.